# python error:List index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

I keep getting the error:

```
line 39, in fetchLocations
locations.add(row[-1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

for the following code

```
def fetchLocations(filename):
  locations = set()
  with open(filename, 'rU') as fileObject:
    csvFile = csv.reader(fileObject, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')
    for row in csvFile:
        #print row[-1]
        locations.add(row[-1])
  return locations
```

However if I uncomment the

```
print row[-1]
```

it works fine. Any clues why this is happening!?

Comment: if you replace "print row[-1]" with  value = row[-1]; print value;locations.add(value)

Comment: @user1474424 Yeah I found that out as well. However the csv file has around 25 million rows! So printing out all those greatly increases the execution time. Wonder why this is happening!